# How to convert CSV file to XML format using linux script in linux box

Tags: linux

I need to convert the CSV file to XML format to meet one of my requirement.
I am completely new for this process.

I have refereed some links like:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Converting%20CSV%20to%20XML

here they have asked to install tools.
But i don't have privilege to install any tool in the server.
So i need to try with any linux script to achieve my task.

before i have used xlsx2csv script for converting xlsx file to csv. in the same manner i am trying to get the script.

I have tried with https://gist.github.com/AnthonyNystrom/5547886
i am not able read the input file it self. I am trying in our linux server

Can any one help me on finding the solution.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This question does not meet SO quality requirements. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools for converting csv to xml. Those could do the job for you.

This site contains multiple tools you can use: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Converting%20CSV%20to%20XML

Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/581265/how-can-i-convert-a-csv-file-to-xml

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have came across the above two links which was shared in first link i am not able to find the solution because they are asking to install. But i am not able to install any tool. So i need a script to do this i am trying with second link which was shared. but i have stuck in middle.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the following code and got the result as excepted 
I have created an shell script and added the below code with an sample csv file like
sample.csv

`id,name,age
    1,Test,23
    2,Testing,32
    3,Cool, 23`

csv2xml.sh

```
`#!/bin/bash
file_in="sample.csv"
file_out="sample.xml"
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' > $file_out
echo '<Customers>' >> $file_out
while IFS=$',' read -r -a arry
do
echo '  <Customer>' >> $file_out
echo '    <Name>'${arry[0]}'</Name>' >> $file_out
echo '    <Age>'${arry[1]}'</Age>' >> $file_out
echo '    <Country>'${arry[2]}'</Country>' >> $file_out
echo '  </Customer>' >> $file_out
done < $file_in
echo '</Customers>' >> $file_out`
```

if we run the above script we will get an sample.xml file.
even we can change the format based on the requirement.
Thanks for the support.